# Entity Framework Customer/Address Relationship

Tags: entity-framework

So I have a situation where I have a `Customer` entity who has a `BillingAddress` and a `ShippingAddress`. That said `Customer` can have multiple of either in say an address book so they can decide where to ship/bill to.

I also have an entity, `SalesOrder` which also has a `BillingAddress` and a `ShippingAddress`.

My question is, should I have a complex type `Address` for the `BillingAddress` and `ShippingAddress`, and then make a say `AddressBookAddress` that inherits from the `Address` and then have collections of that on the `Customer`?

I had this question here: [Entity Framework 5.0 Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699976/entity-framework-5-0-relationships)

That solves the `Customer` billing and shipping address problem, but it seems like I am going to end up with a couple different types that are the same for the most part.

Comment: Im not sure what the question is, what you are suggesting sounds like a sensible design decision?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a single `Address` entity to store all addresses.

A `Customer` entity can have 0..n addresses through an intermediate table `Customer_Address`.

A `SalesOrder` entity can have a `BillingAddress` and a `ShippingAddress`, each of which is a link to an `Address` entity.